# Barcode Login Solution

Tags: windows, gratis, time-management, authentication

I am looking for a login solution that allows you to use a school photo id card to authenticate a Windows PC.

**Requirements:**

- Must work with ANY barcode type
- Must be *Freware*
- Preferable if it can be managed over a network
- Must be able to lock certain barcodes
- Preferable if you can group barcodes / name barcodes